# How do I use wp_editor() in widget form?

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm trying to use the built-in Rich-text (wp_editor()) editor in Wordpress for my widget, but I can't seem to find any simple way to use it..

I know you can use it, as [Black Studio TinyMCE](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/) can do it, but how?

**My form function**

```
function form($instance)
{
    $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, array( 'box1' => '', 'box2' => '', 'box3' => '', 'box4' => '' ));
    $box1 = $instance['box1'];
    $box2 = $instance['box2'];
    $box3 = $instance['box3'];
    $box4 = $instance['box4'];
    $boxqty = $instance['boxqty'];

?>
  <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('boxqty'); ?>">Number of blocks: (1-4) <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('boxqty'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('boxqty'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($boxqty); ?>" /></label></p>  
  <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box1'); ?>">Box 1:
     <textarea class="widefat mceEditor" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('box1'); ?>">  <?php echo $box1; ?></textarea>
   </label></p>
   <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box2'); ?>">Box 2: 
      <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('box2'); ?>"><?php echo $box2; ?></textarea>
   </p>
   <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box3'); ?>">Box 3: 
<textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box3'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('box3'); ?>"><?php echo $box3; ?></textarea>
   </p>
   <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box4'); ?>">Box 4: 
      <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('box4'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('box4'); ?>"><?php echo $box4; ?>      </textarea>
   </p>
<?php
   wp_editor('Test text', 'test-editor');
}
```

Comment: Did you read the related questions here? Look at the sidebar. Tell us what you have tried already and what didn’t work.

Comment: Yes, I did read them, but I can't seem to find a simple answer.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled across this solution a while back; this might be what you are looking for:

I added this to my theme's functions.php file...

```
// First, I created a shortcode for a function, that would typically be inserted in to a template file, so that it could be inserted in to a widget.

add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'myfunction');
function myfunction() {
  if ( function_exists( 'get_smooth_slider_category' ) ) { get_smooth_slider_category('featured'); }
}

// Then you can add this to allow shortcodes to be used in widgets.

/* Make shortcodes work in widgets */
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Then I just added `[myshortcode]` to the text widget and viola; I have a function in a widget.

Comment: I'm not sure, what this has to do with my question.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I thought this was little simpler than it is. I might have a suggestion though. Take a look at the plugin wp-user-frontend and look at how the developer added the editor to pages. You'll find the code in wpuf-editor.php and add-post.php. Hope this helps.